# How to count total receipts by date

Tags: sql, ssms-2016

Would like to know why do I keep getting the error message?

Created query with SQL Server Management Studio, my output to display correctly has parameters, and I have tried the following with my query.

What I really would like is to have a specific start and end dates and change selected dates with any other combination of `MinDate`, `MaxDate` as follows:

```
@MinDate DATE = '2020-01-01',
@MaxDate DATE = '2020-02-01';
```

Totals:

```
COUNT(Receipt_ID) AS 'Total_Number_Of_Receipts',
SUM(Receipt_Amount) AS 'Total_Amount'
```

This is the error I get:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
> Incorrect syntax near '.'.
>
> Msg 8158, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
> 'Receipt_Date' has more columns than were specified in the column list.

Query:

```
DECLARE 
    @MinDate DATE = '2020-01-01',
    @MaxDate DATE = '2020-02-01';

WITH Receipt_Date(day) AS
(
    SELECT,
        DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()) AS 'Yesterday',
        COUNT(Receipt_ID) AS 'Total_Number_Of_Receipts',
        SUM(Receipt_Amount) AS 'Total_Amount'
    FROM 
        receipts AS r
    WHERE 
        CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, day) AS Date) < @MaxDate
)
SELECT * 
FROM receipts AS r
```

Comment: Within SSMS, the editor is your friend - e.g, what is the IDE highlighting as problem areas of this query which might lead to the syntax errors you're receiving? With regards to the query, it's not clear what the schema of `receipts` looks like and how it relates to any date fields - are you trying to generate a list of dates between a `MinDate` and `MaxDate` and provide aggregates on the individual dates that fall between?

Comment: @ Anthony Forloney, regarding individual dates that fall between, yes, I am looking to have MinDate and MaxDate generate receipt total count with Total Amount per between dates.

Comment: Based on that it seems like what you're trying to achieve is: 1) leverage CTE to be _recursive_ to build out ALL possible dates between the `MinDate` and `MaxDate`, 2) from the resultant CTE of all possible dates, using that to `JOIN` against the `receipts` table to aggregate upon - does that sound like it's what you're looking for?

Comment: @Anthony Forloney, yes that is what I am looking for, 1) leverage CTE to be recursive to build out ALL possible dates between the MinDate and MaxDate, 2) from the resultant CTE of all possible dates, using that to JOIN against the receipts table to aggregate.

Comment: Added an answer which should help you achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1: You've got a comma after the select inside your CTE

```
SELECT, --<< here
        DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()) AS 'Yesterday',
```

2: You need to match the definition of the CTE with the columns being returned, so you can't just have 'day' if you're returning 4 columns in the CTE

3: In your select statement you need to reference the CTE.

This returns, but I've no example data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #receipts;

CREATE TABLE #receipts
(
Receipt_ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
d DATE,
Receipt_Amount MONEY
);

DECLARE 
    @MinDate DATE = '2020-01-01',
    @MaxDate DATE = '2020-02-01';

WITH Receipt_Date(Yesterday, Total_Number_Of_Receipts, Total_Amount) AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD([day], -1, GETDATE()) AS 'Yesterday',
        COUNT(Receipt_ID) AS 'Total_Number_Of_Receipts',
        SUM(Receipt_Amount) AS 'Total_Amount'
    FROM 
        #receipts AS r
    WHERE 
        CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, d) AS Date) < @MaxDate
    GROUP BY DATEADD([day], -1, GETDATE())
)

SELECT * 
FROM Receipt_Date;
```

Comment: problem after running your query. Would you know why MinDate with MaxDate does not return range date request:
    MinDate DATE = '2020-01-01',
    MaxDate DATE = '2020-02-01';

Minimum Dates Starts from YEAR 2006, moving forward and its gathering hundreds of rows, and not my selected range.

Comment: Just realised I was missing a group by. Also, the #receipts tempt table needs to be replaced with your source table, that temp table has nothing in it..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, you can approach the solution by using a *recursive CTE* to help generate the list of dates which fall between a `MinDate` and `MaxDate`.

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATE = '2020-01-01', @MaxDate DATE = '2020-02-01';

;WITH Receipts_CTE(receipt_date) AS
(
    SELECT @MinDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, receipt_date)
    FROM Receipts_CTE
    WHERE receipt_date < @MaxDate
)
```

This will recursively call itself to *add 1 day to the running receipt_date column* until it reaches the specified `MaxDate`.

With this CTE building out all the necessary dates, you can then use the dates from this CTE to `JOIN` against your source table to build out the necessary aggregate.

Without knowing the schema of the `receipts` table in question, the below is merely used for illustration purposes:

```
SELECT receipts.Receipt_Date,
       COUNT(receipts.Receipt_ID) AS TotalReceipts,
       SUM(receipts.Receipt_Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Receipts receipts
INNER JOIN Reciepts_CTE cte ON cte.receipt_date = receipts.Receipt_Date
GROUP BY receipts.Receipt_Date
```